# Exposing javascript template to end users

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I want to allow an end user do some customization by allowing them to specify a template string which gets evaluated in the context of an object filled with user accessible variables. However, I have seen [concerned raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946416/how-safe-is-to-allow-customer-edit-handlebar-js-template) about this. I only really need to give the user access to the printing of defined values. Allowing them to call code is unnecessary and will just add too much complexity to a minor feature.

Pseudo-code for the only functionality I need:

```
var userTemplate = "{{Persons.Total}} persons including {{Persons.First}}";
var variables = { Persons { Total: 10, First: "Bob" } };
return template(userTemplate, variables); // = "10 persons including Bob"
```

Are there any template libraries out there that are 'user safe'? Or should I just do it myself with a bunch of regex?

Comment: We'll gladly offer a workaround, but could you be a bit more specific as to what you're trying to accomplish? You may not need to have a user type in a near object literal.

Answer (score 0):

[OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.230_-_Never_Insert_Untrusted_Data_Except_in_Allowed_Locations) contains many rules for sanitizing user input in order to prevent cross site scripting (aka javascript injection).

Rule6 is of particular interest as it discusses using an HTML Policy engine to validate or clean user-driven HTML in an outbound way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a bunch of regex? In your simple case, just checking that there is no tag should be enough:

```
regex=/<[\s\S]+>/
```